# C# ParameterizedThread starts with action of next object in foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've faced a problem with multithreading in C#. I'm starting threads by foreach of Dictionary objects.

The problem is that plugin object gets overwriten with next dictionary object before ParameterizedThread starts.

How i could solve this issue without using something like Thread.Sleep(10) or waiting for ThreadState changed to "Running"?

```
_pluginWorkers = new Dictionary<string, Action<DateTime, DateTime>>();

... Filling _pluginWorkers with objects ...

foreach (var plugin in _pluginWorkers)
{
    var pluginAction = new ParameterizedThreadStart(obj => plugin.Value(timestart, timeend));
    Thread actionThread = new Thread(pluginAction, 1024 * 1024);
    actionThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: @HansPassant So you think that the OP is using a C# compiler of version 4 or earlier?  It's not impossible but it's...unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, Hans Passant. That's exactly what it was. P.S. I'm using .net 3.5.

Comment: @Rincew1nd The version of .NET that you're using is irrelevant to this behavior.  What matters is the compiler version.